# How to use a router outlet from another module

Tags: angular

I don't know how to explain this so I am just going to illustrate

**[admin-layout.module has admin-layout.routin**g]

```
@NgModule({
    RouterModule.forChild(AdminLayoutRoutes),
    ...
})
```

**[admin-layout.routing has property.component]**

```
export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'property', component: PropertyComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
...
]
```

**[property.component.html has ]**

```
<div class="card-body mt-3">
    <app-parameters></app-parameters>
</div>
```

**[pamaters.component.html has ]**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/soadate']" routerLinkActive="active" >SOA DATE</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have a soadate.component that needs to be seen at the router-outlet of patameters.component.html

**[This soadate.component is inside the paramters.module.ts]**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(ParametersRoutes),
    ],
    declarations: [
        SoaDateComponent
    ]
})
```

and this is the ParametersRoutes.routing

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SoaDateComponent } from './soa-date/soa-date.component';

export const ParametersRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'soadate', component: SoaDateComponent}
];
```

Please show me how I can see the **soadate.component.html** inside the **parameters.component.html** as soon as I click the `<a [routerLink]="['/soadate']" routerLinkActive="active" >SOA DATE</a>`

Thank you.

Comment: any error in `console`?

Comment: look for `children` route attribute . https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I don't get any errors. I can actually get to the html the problem is it is not inside the second router outlet meaning it is not in the router outlet of the paramteters.component.html. It gets shown in the first router outlet which is in the admin-layout.component.html

Comment: Maybe you will be interested in **Auxiliary Routes**